# Jeckyll's Docker image with make

Tags: ruby, docker, jekyll

I need a Jekyll's Docker image with `make` (for compiling `oj` that requires ruby 2 instead of 1.9):

```
$ docker run --volume=$(pwd):/srv/jekyll jekyll/jekyll:pages jekyll serve

creating Makefile
extconf.rb:68:in ``': No such file or directory - make (Errno::ENOENT)
```

It fails with the standard Jekyll's Docker image because `make` is missing:

```
$ docker run -it jekyll/jekyll:pages bash
bash-4.3# make
bash: make: command not found
```

The `zachdeibert/jekyll` image that includes `make` lacks the ruby's header needed to compile.

**Do I need to make a Dockerfile to have a Jeckyll's Docker image with make?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own Dockerfile.

Here is an example:

```
FROM jekyll/jekyll

RUN apk --update --no-cache add make \
    && gem install oj

CMD jekyll serve
```

Then you build it:

```
docker build -t testoj .
```

and finally you use it

```
docker run -d --name ojinstance testoj
```